# CSS Not Rendering After A Post Submit Using Express

Tags: javascript, css, express

I was able to get the CSS loaded on the initial page of the get, but when I use a button to submit data using POST, The post works, but the CSS fails to load and the screen is just plain with post info. here is some info below

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); 

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})
```

The HTML

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="n1" placeholder="First Number">
    <input type="text" name="n2" placeholder="Second Number">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>

</form>
```

The post

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){

    var num1 = Number(req.body.n1); 
    var num2 = Number(req.body.n2);

    var result = num1 + num2;

    res.send("The result is " + result);
})
```

Page loads background color fine, but when I hit the calculate button is when CSS doesn't load. Just wondering what else I'd need to do to make CSS appear everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

On the initial `GET` request, aside from the form part, you are probably responding with a static html file that in turn references css files.

That's not the case when you hit the "Calculate" button. On that `POST` request you are responding with plain text ("The result is x"), not HTML, and that doesn't reference any styles whatsoever.

You may want to look into some templating engine like Handlebars, EJS, or something more flexible like Vue, Svelte, React or Angular.